# Ignoring global HasQueryFilter() for an administrator in a ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I need to allow a 'SuperUser' overall access to data and views across multiple tenants.

I use a single database and a single codebase for  the app. To isolate the data for each tenant a filter has been created in the modelbuilder in `ApplicationDbContext`.

However, the superuser should be able to bypass this filter and have access to all data (let's not worry, if that is a good thing or not). I know I can accomplish this by adding the `IgnoreQueryFilters()`, but then I need to add this to each and every filter.

Is there a way to accomplish this globally?

Your guidance is very much appreciated.

**Edit**

I have added the complete and revised ApplicationDbContext and Program.cs. Why does the if-statement around the codeblock `HasQueryFilter()` not work?

As was stated by Panagiotis Kanavos, the code should not call `HasQueryFilter` if the User is an Administrator. But how to accomlplish this? I tried below code, but that did not work.

*ApplicationDbContext*

```
using Whatever.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Whatever.Data
{
    public partial class ApplicationDbContext : 
IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string,
    IdentityUserClaim<string>, ApplicationUserRole, 
IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, 
IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    public 
ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> 
options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _contextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
   
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRole { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tenant> Tenant { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TenantPerson> TenantPerson { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CustomerMember> CustomerMember { get; set; }              

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);           

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
            .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
            .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
            .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
            .IsRequired();
        });      
          
        if(!_contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("SuperUser"))  // Does not work properly
        {       
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.Id == CurrentTenantId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<TenantPerson>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == CurrentTenantId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == CurrentTenantId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerMember>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == CurrentTenantId);
        }          

        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Profile)
        .WithOne(e => e.Project)
            .HasForeignKey<Profile>(e => e.ProjectId)
            .IsRequired(false);
    }

    public virtual Guid CurrentTenantId => GetCurrentTenantId();

  private Guid GetCurrentTenantId()
  {
     string cUsername = _contextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User.Identity?.Name ?? string.Empty;
     ApplicationUser? storedUser = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == cUsername);
     return storedUser?.TenantId ?? Guid.Empty;
  }
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

*Program.cs*

```
using Whatever.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = 
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole> 
   (options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");        
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Customer}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: `.IgnoreQueryFilters` maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.ignorequeryfilters?view=efcore-8.0 Have you considered using Row Level Security for this (it would be applied at the database level)

Comment: @Charlieface: I am using `.IgnoreQueryFilters` on a local level. But how to apply that on the global level of the app? I tried making the `HasQueryFilter` conditional in the `OnModelCreating`, but that did not work.

Comment: How do you determine that a user is an administrator? The easiest thing is to *not* call `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasQueryFilter(` if the user is an administrator.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I did that by enclosing the `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasQueryFilter(` in a if-statement if(_contextAssessor.User.IsinRole("SuperUser"). That did work, but only when logging-in for the first time. When logging out and logging in as another User, the `.HasQueryFilter()` did not kick in.

Comment: That's caused by code that's not included in the question. It would only happen if the DbContext is a Singleton, you have a Blazor Server application or you tried to use DbContext in a Singleton background service. DbContext is meant to be scoped. Its concurrency model actually depends on this. `AddDbContext` registers the context as a scoped object. In ASP.NET Core the scope is the request which means a new DbContext is created for every request, so `OnModelBuilding` executes on every request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test , your logic of retrieving the currentName is not finished correctly in `modelCreating` . The `HasQueryFilter` method needs to reference a property that is evaluated when the query is executed, not when the model is being built . Here is a code sample .

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    : base(options)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public DbSet<TenantPerson> TenantPersons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid CurrentTenantId => GetCurrentTenantId();

    public bool ShouldApplyTenantFilter()
    {
        // Replace the logic below with your actual superuser check
        var isSuperUser = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Super");
        return !isSuperUser;
    }

    private Guid GetCurrentTenantId()
    {
        string cUserName = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name ?? string.Empty;
        ApplicationUser sUser = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == cUserName);
        return sUser?.TenantId ?? Guid.Empty;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //Logic of verifying if run into the filter
        modelBuilder.Entity<TenantPerson>().HasQueryFilter(e => ShouldApplyTenantFilter() ? e.TenantId == CurrentTenantId : true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasQueryFilter(e => ShouldApplyTenantFilter() ? e.TenantId == CurrentTenantId : true);
    }
}
```

When SuperUser is logged , it will bypass the filter, get all the records .

[image]

When normal user is logged , filter will work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There's no reason to call `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasQueryFilter(` if you already know the user is an administrator. What you posted is known as a [catch-all query](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/revisiting-catch-all-queries) that results in inefficient execution plans

Comment: Thanks! Your answer solved my problem. Howwever, I agree with Panagiotis that it would be even better *not* to call the QueryFilter at all.